# Activating HP iLO license from Windows command line

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp-proliant

Is there any possibility to enter licence activation key to iLO3 in Windows command line? Or any other tool that will allow me to do that on about three hundred servers (HP Proliant ML110 G7)?

Comment: In case if someone else has the same problem:
1.Download and modify [link](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/itrc-298/3015/1/294633.xml)
2.Copy it on your machine to C:\some\location (of course you can rename it)
3.Run `"C:\Program Files\HP\hponcfg\hponcfg.exe" /f C:\some\location\294633.xml`

Comment: Michal, you post his as your own answer.